# ExecuteNonQuery doesn't return results

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my (rough) code (DAL):

```
int i;
// Some other declarations

SqlCommand myCmdObject = new SqlCommand("some query");

conn.open();
i = myCmdObject.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.close();
```

The problem is: Even though there is a record present on my `SELECT` query, the value in `i` remains `-1`.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

What kind of query do you perform? Using `ExecuteNonQuery` is intended for `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE` queries. As per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx):

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE
>   statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the
>   command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the
>   return value includes the number of
>   rows affected by both the insert or
>   update operation and the number of
>   rows affected by the trigger or
>   triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1.

Comment: What is the return value, if we run a StoredProcedure which will Insert or Update or Delete a Record in a Table,

Answer (score 19):

Whenever you want to execute an SQL statement that shouldn't return a value or a record set, the ExecuteNonQuery should be used.

So if you want to run an update, delete, or insert statement, you should use the ExecuteNonQuery. ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected by the statement. This sounds very nice, but whenever you use the SQL Server 2005 IDE or Visual Studio to create a stored procedure it adds a small line that ruins everything.

That line is: SET NOCOUNT ON; This line turns on the NOCOUNT feature of SQL Server, which "Stops the message indicating the number of rows affected by a Transact-SQL statement from being returned as part of the results" and therefore it makes the stored procedure always to return -1 when called from the application (in my case a web application).

In conclusion, remove that line from your stored procedure, and you will now get a value indicating the number of rows affected by the statement.

Happy programming!

http://aspsoft.blogs.com/jonas/2006/10/executenonquery.html

Answer (score 8):

You use `EXECUTENONQUERY()` for `INSERT`,`UPDATE` and `DELETE`.

But for `SELECT` you must use `EXECUTEREADER()`.........

Answer (score 7):

Because the SET NOCOUNT option is set to on. Remove the line "SET NOCOUNT ON;" in your query or stored procedure.

See more at *[SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() returns -1 when doing Insert / Update / Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.7.2)*.

Comment: your link is dead

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN:  [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery)

> You can use the ExecuteNonQuery to
> perform catalog operations (for
> example, querying the structure of a
> database or creating database objects
> such as tables), or to change the data
> in a database without using a DataSet
> by executing UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE
> statements.
>
> Although the ExecuteNonQuery returns
> no rows, any output parameters or
> return values mapped to parameters are
> populated with data.
>
> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE
> statements, the return value is the
> number of rows affected by the
> command. When a trigger exists on a
> table being inserted or updated, the
> return value includes the number of
> rows affected by both the insert or
> update operation and the number of
> rows affected by the trigger or
> triggers. **For all other types of
> statements, the return value is -1**. If
> a rollback occurs, the return value is
> also -1.

You are using SELECT query, thus you get -1

Answer (score 1):

Could you post the exact query? The `ExecuteNonQuery` method returns the `@@ROWCOUNT` Sql Server variable what ever it is after the last query has executed is what the `ExecuteNonQuery` method returns.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to get just a single integer from the query, use:

```
myCmdObject.ExecuteScalar()
```

Comment: ExecuteScalar will return only on value that is first column value of the first row in the executed query.

Comment: That is true but as i said when selecting single integer it is supposed to be in the first column of the first row :)

Answer (score 1):

The `ExecuteNonQuery` method is used for SQL statements that are **not** queries, such as `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, ... You want to use `ExecuteScalar` or `ExecuteReader` if you expect your statement to return results (i.e. a query).

Answer (score 0):

> if you want to run an update, delete,
>   or insert statement, you should use
>   the ExecuteNonQuery. ExecuteNonQuery
>   returns the number of rows affected by
>   the statement.

[How to Set Count On](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/01/27/sqlcommand-executenonquery-returns-1-when-doing-insert-update-delete.aspx)