# connecting sql database to asp.net using vb

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

i have a table in database name user (username,userid,country). i want to retrieve the data in asp.net. but i have problem in connecting sql database. this is my code

```
Public Sub connect()
    Dim DatabaseName As String = "user"
    Dim server As String = "loalhost"
    Dim userName As String = "me"
    Dim password As String = " "
    If Not conn Is Nothing Then conn.Close()
    conn.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false", server, userName, password, DatabaseName)
End Sub
```

i try this to retrieve the data using this code but error

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT username FROM user"))
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Please share us the error your getting

Comment: there is error at cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: 1) You can use an [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx). 2) It's "localhost", not "loalhost".

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ExecuteReader to get all the data...as ExecuteNonQuery() is used to update database

```
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            //GridView2.DataSource = reader;
            //GridView2.DataBind();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
               String username =Convert.ToString(reader["username"]);
               // ServicePointDetails t = new ServicePointDetails();
               // t.ServicePointID = Convert.ToString(reader["ServicePointID"]);
               // t.ServicePointName = Convert.ToString(reader["ServicePointName"]);
              //  servicePointDetails_list.Add(t);
            }
```

for more info [ExecuteNonQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349114/executenonquery)

vb.net

```
Dim data As SqlDataReader
Dim command As New SqlCommand
command.CommandText = sqlquery
command.Connection = conn
data = cmd.ExecuteReader()
While data.Read
    If data.HasRows = True Then
        Dim userName As String
        userName = data.Item("username")
        //Pupulate a list/do something else 
    End If
End While
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your tablename is incorrect: Database is User and what is the table name? Provide correct table name in query

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT username FROM yourtablename"))
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the String.Format

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT username FROM user")
```

Is the table name USERS not USER?

Why are you using String.Format for the connection string?

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
...
Dim strConnection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Something").ConnectionString
Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnection)

Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [username] FROM YourTableNameHere", con)
ds = New DataSet
da.Fill(ds, "MyDataTableName")
da.Dispose()
```

Dataset (ds) now contains a list of usernames and if in a function, return the results:

```
Return ds
```

Comment: There is an error at Dim strConnection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Something").ConnectionString. ConfigurationManager are not declared. but i have added imports system.configuration. it still doesnt work

Comment: ConfigurationManager  does not work since i use vb 2003

Comment: What version of Framework? Version 2 uses it slightly differently, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings(v=vs.80).aspx