# AVG QUERY in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Good morning, I'm developing a code that can get me out of my database in sql, the AVG of a certain column.
The problem is that I'm not getting it, I think the problem is the query but I do not know how to solve it.
I need help, thank you.

Here is the code:

```
String connectionString =
       "Data Source=localhost;" +
       "Initial Catalog=DB_SACC;" +
       "User id=sa;" +
       "Password=1234;";

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        string textt = " USE [DB_SACC] SELECT AVG (Total_Divida) FROM t_pagamentos";

        cmd.CommandText = textt;

        connection.Open();

        cmd.Connection = connection;

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (textt == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("nothing");
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox3.Text = textt;
        }
```

Comment: Hint: you are executing a query with `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349114/executenonquery

Comment: Use `ExecuteScalar()` store its out put in some object and then access it

Comment: isn't a `GROUP BY` needed for `AVG` ?

Comment: what do i put in the TextBox? To return the query value!

Comment: why everyone are voting down

Comment: @FelixD. no it doesn't need that

Answer (score 2):

Use cmd.ExecuteScalar() method instead:

```
decimal average = (decimal) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` only returns the number of rows effected where as what you want is to read the result set of `SELECT` statement.

I would also get rid of `USE [DB_SACC]` from your `SELECT` statement since you are defining the database name in your connection string.

**EDIT**

Your code should look like this:

```
string textt = "SELECT AVG (Total_Divida) FROM t_pagamentos";
cmd.CommandText = textt;
connection.Open();
cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
decimal average = (decimal) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (textt == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("nothing");
}
else
{
    TextBox3.Text = average.ToString();
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
try
{
    string textt = "SELECT AVG (Total_Divida) FROM t_pagamentos";
    cmd.CommandText = textt;
    connection.Open();
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    decimal average = (decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    TextBox3.Text = average.ToString();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     // log your exception here...
     MessageBox.Show("nothing");
}
```

**EDIT 3:**

In the light of your recent comments try this

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=DB_SACC; User id=sa Password=1234;";
        decimal? average;
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    string textt = "SELECT AVG (Total_Divida) AS 'AVG_DIVIDA' FROM t_pagamentos";
                    cmd.CommandText = textt;
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    using (DataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            average = decimal.parse(reader["AVG_DIVIDA"].ToString());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            TextBox3.Text = average.HasValue ? average.ToString() : "Unknown error occurred";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to retrieve the average, reason: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

*Note: Using DataReader to get just single value from database is not preferred. I am proposing this because of the error you mentioned in the comments.*

If you are getting any SQL Exception then try to run this statement on SQL Server as stand alone test.

```
USE DB_SACC
GO

SELECT AVG (Total_Divida) AS 'AVG_DIVIDA' FROM t_pagamentos
GO
```

If you still encounter any error while executing T-SQL Statement then please post that as another question.

Comment: I had a problem with the code. Is giving the following error: column not found. help please

Comment: Could you run the select statement on the sql server and see if it works?

Comment: it gives this error : Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 't_pagamentos'

Comment: Thats your table which looks like sql server is unable to find. Try running this before the select statement

Comment: Use db_sacc go;

Comment: Now the query is well-scanned in the database, but I continue with the error despite having changed the query in my code

Comment: What do you mean by "well-scanned"? How could you continue with error? It could have knock-on effect on your program. I have updated my answer with EDIT 3 for you.

Answer (score 2):

- use `ExecuteScalar` if you request a single value from your database - `ExecuteNonQuery` returns just the number of affected rows which is used in update / insert statements
- `USE [DB_SACC]` is not required in your query since you define the `"Initial Catalog=DB_SACC;"`
- add `using` to avoid open connections

Code:

```
string connectionString =  "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DB_SACC;User id=sa;Password=1234;";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string textt = "SELECT AVG (Total_Divida) FROM t_pagamentos";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(textt, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var result =  cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //write the result into a variable

        if (result == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("nothing");
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox3.Text = result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a problem with the code. Is giving the following error: column not found. help please