# C# MySQL Order By Returns -1

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to get the last row of a table using C# but it doesn't seem to be working, this is my code:

```
MySqlConnection cnnGetID = new MySqlConnection(Global.connectionString);

cmd = "SELECT ContactID FROM Contacten ORDER BY ContactID DESC LIMIT 1";
MySqlCommand cmdGetID = new MySqlCommand(cmd, cnnGetID);

cnnGetID.Open();
string contactID = cmdGetID.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
MessageBox.Show(contactID);

cnnGetID.Close();
```

The value this returns is -1 while it should be returning 59.

The strange thing is is that when I run this command in phpmyadmin I DO get 59.

Any ideas on why C# is not returning the correct value but phpmyadmin is?

EDIT: problem solved, should've uses ExecuteScalar(). Looks like I've been staring at my monitor for a bit too long...

Comment: Lesson to learn here: read the names of the methods you're calling carefully, and read their documentation carefully.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349114/executenonquery - Using ExecuteNonQuery is intended for UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`.

```
MySqlConnection cnnGetID = new MySqlConnection(Global.connectionString);

cmd = "SELECT ContactID FROM Contacten ORDER BY ContactID DESC LIMIT 1";
MySqlCommand cmdGetID = new MySqlCommand(cmd, cnnGetID);

cnnGetID.Open();
string contactID = cmdGetID.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
MessageBox.Show(contactID);
cnnGetID.Close();
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: I have no clue how I didn't see that haha, looks like I've been staring at my monitor for a bit too long!

Answer (score 1):

you should use `ExecuteScalar` because you are returning value `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected by update delete or insert opeation

you can check this for more info

**ExecuteNonQuery**

> Returns the number of rows affected.

**ExecuteScalar**

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in
>   the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are
>   ignored.

for more information you can check this  [The MySqlCommand Object](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html)

Comment: You've linked to `SqlCommand` documentation - this is `MySqlCommand`. That's why I linked to `IDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for the correction sir i have updated the link

Answer (score 1):

> The value this returns is -1 while it should be returning 59.

No, it's behaving exactly as documented by [`IDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idbcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.7):

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.

You're using a `SELECT` statement - a *query*. So instead of executing `ExecuteNonQuery`, you should be using `ExecuteQuery` and iterating over the results, or `ExecuteScalar`, given that you know you'll have a single result:

```
string contactID = cmdGetID.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use query like this

```
MySqlConnection cnnGetID = new MySqlConnection(Global.connectionString);

cmd = "SELECT TOP 1 ContactID FROM Contacten ORDER BY ContactID";
MySqlCommand cmdGetID = new MySqlCommand(cmd, cnnGetID);

cnnGetID.Open();
string contactID = cmdGetID.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
MessageBox.Show(contactID);

cnnGetID.Close();
```